# Lifetime of deleted answer

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers

I deleted my answer, but it's still available for me, for moderators and for 10K+ reputation users. How long will this deleted answer exist on Stack Overflow?

Comment: If you want, you can flag answers / contact the support team to anonymize your questions / answers.

Comment: The canonical question (part of the official FAQ) is *["What does deletion mean for a post?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)* (cross-site), for this case near *"What does deletion mean for a post?"*.

Comment: Is there a similar question on this site?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Forever.

Stack Overflow only soft-deletes posts, except in extreme circumstances. This gives authors a chance to go back and fix a post if it needs it, or for other users to undelete a wrongfully deleted post.

I wouldn't worry about it, however. In the case of an author delete, your post will remain deleted unless you undelete it or the mods suspect foul play. (A rage quit, say.) Since you're asking here, I highly doubt you're rage quitting.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. It's very strange that deleted answers has infinite storage time. I think it's no good because the size of database will grow up all the time

Comment: @VideoProcessingResearcher yeah they take up space, but they get more questions anyway so it's not really a problem.

Comment: @VideoProcessingResearcher At this point, Stack Overflow has indicated a couple times that they aren't worried about the database space, so we shouldn't either. Now if the calls start to slow down... Then we can yell at them. ;)

Comment: @VideoProcessingResearcher I'd also note that while you/others with 10k+ can see them if you have a direct link it's to all intents and purposes "gone". Only mods can see deleted posts on a user profile page or search for deleted posts for another user. The chances of anyone happening upon it is negligible.

Comment: @JonClements for a question - you are correct.  But for an answer, anyone with those privleges will see it if they visit the question.  Certainly not a high value, but probably likely than negligible

Comment: @psubsee2003 an active question in popular tags with 10k+ privilege users viewing it then yes... I'll concede it's a bit more than negligible but in this case it was an answer to  a two year old question that's been viewed 145 times... The chances of a 10k user viewing it now are slim enough it could be considered so :)

Comment: You could reference [the canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374990/lifetime-of-deleted-answer?cb=1#comment636172_374990) in your answer.

Comment: It would be sensible to eventually have them nuked permanently though. Not so much for reducing disk space, as for reducing clutter on the site. But that's for another thread.

Comment: @VideoProcessingResearcher Questions are *text*, and text does not take much space and can also be compressed incredibly well (e.g. compressing log files can reduce the size by 90+%). I'd bet that the space occupied by the pictures uploaded on stackoverflow takes more space than the text of questions/answers/comment when compressed properly.

Answer (score 10):

Forever. It's never removed from the server in the event that you might want to undelete it.

In fact, the [sandbox on PPCG](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) has so many deleted answers that the 10Kers are wishing that they could hide them.

Comment: The question itself gets unprotected about once a month, too.

Comment: @Draco18s no, I think Shog fixed that for them a while back.

Comment: I couldn't recall if that was a Thing or if I'd imagined it.

Comment: It's absurd to keep 2, 3, 5 or 10 years old wrong answers in the database. If I don't undelete my answer shortly after, will never happen because it's rubbish.